# .net core 6 exception processing unknown request headers

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a web application whose sole purpose is to redirect shortened links (custom in-house bitly). There is no public facing HTML returned, you come to the site/[slug] and you get redirected to final destination. I capture exceptions using Serilog and I'm getting this stack trace logged every day:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.StringUtilities.GetAsciiOrUTF8StringNonNullCharacters(ReadOnlySpan`1 span, Encoding defaultEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.HeaderEncoding.GetString(Byte* pBytes, Int32 byteCount, Boolean useLatin1)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.NativeRequestContext.GetUnknownHeadersHelper(IDictionary`2 unknownHeaders, Int64 fixup, HTTP_REQUEST* request)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.NativeRequestContext.GetUnknownHeaders(IDictionary`2 unknownHeaders)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.RequestHeaders.get_Extra()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.RequestHeaders.get_Item(String key)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.RequestHeaders.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHeaderDictionary.get_ContentLength()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.CheckRequestCanHaveBody()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.InitializeContext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
```

I have never seen this exception before nor has the Internet, cause I have googled it extensively. Based on the trace, it looks like someone may be sending me requests with some garbage in the request headers. So my first plan was to inject middleware to attempt to strip out all of the headers from the request and only keep the user-agent (all I care about). This did not work as this exception still occurs, so my middle ware attempt did not happen early enough.

Has anyone else seen this and have a remediation?

Comment: The error shows `GetAsciiOrUTF8StringNonNullCharacters` complaining about the input string. If you search in the ASP.NET Core Github repo you'll [find the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/99a1d2c0cb39cbddb0e771d76c15fa96cae46261/src/Shared/ServerInfrastructure/StringUtilities.cs#L25). It complains when it finds NUL characters (0x00) in a string. What request caused this?

Comment: `redirect shortened links (custom in-house bitly).` that sounds like a job for [YARP](https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy).

Comment: I don't have access to the request because the call never reaches my code to inspect/log anything about it.

Comment: IIS has request logging too. You can configure request logging in IIS to see what's actually being sent

Comment: So someone is hitting my site sending in header data with NUL in it, how do I circumvent this?

Comment: *Log the requests in IIS first* to see what's going on.

Comment: Check [HTTP Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httplogging). This can be configured in `web.config` or in IIS Manager

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252577/discussion-between-stuart-allen-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: check IIS logs to find out the problematic request looks like a great idea.